# AngularJS .then of undefined

Tags: angularjs, http-post, angular-promise

I have a payload that I am posting to an API. I'm calling the method that calls the API from my controller as so:

```
 arisService.getVarStatData(
                JSON.stringify($scope.payload),
                JSON.stringify($scope.config.index_info),
                field,
                stat
                )
                .then(function (data) {

                    $scope.varStat = data;

                    console.log("var stat data", $scope.varStat);
                });
```

In my service, since FIELD is an array, I have a for loop pushing the values of the array to the payload and then calling a function with the payload as a parameter:

```
 function getVarStatData(payload, index, field, stat) {

        for (var i = 0; i < field.length; i++) {
            if (field[i]) {

                var varStatData = {
                    user_selection: payload,
                    index_info: index,
                    field: field[i],
                    statistic: stat

                };

                postStatData(varStatData);

            }
        }
    }

    function postStatData(varStatData){
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $http({
            url: 'API',
            method: "POST",
            data: $.param(varStatData),
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        }).then(function (response) {
            var varStat = response.data;

            console.log("variable stat response data", varStat);

            deferred.resolve(varStat);
        });

        return deferred.promise;

    }
```

Now I'm able to perfectly get the data in my service but in my controller I get an error "cannot read property of .then of undefined. Initially I wasn't resolving the promises using $q so I made of it and figured that would do the job but no luck. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do something after multiple asynchronous function calls you can use `.all()`.

```
function getVarStatData(payload, index, field, stat) {
    var promises = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < field.length; i++) {
        if (field[i]) {

            var varStatData = {
                user_selection: payload,
                index_info: index,
                field: field[i],
                statistic: stat

            };

            promises.push(postStatData(varStatData));

        }
    }
    return $q.all(promises);
}
```

The `all` promise gets resolved with an array of resolutions to the promises it got. 
See the documentation on this page - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Comment: This actually did away with the ".then undefined" error but my data comes back as "undefined"...any thoughts? I re-checked my payloads and looks good when it gets posted. The data logs as expected in my service but once it gets to my controller, its undefined...@Brannon Heftel

Comment: also, I logged the promise that gets returned and the data in that as well is undefined...this is in the service

Comment: sorry for the delay - you are logging the varStat variable still? did you look at the response, or just response.data?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is promise object is not getting returned from the `getVarStatData` method, so you need to return the `postStatData` function from `getVarStatData` method.

```
function getVarStatData(payload, index, field, stat) {
   var result = [], promise;
   for (var i = 0; i < field.length; i++) {
     if (field[i]) {
       var varStatData = {
         user_selection: payload,
         index_info: index,
         field: field[i],
         statistic: stat

       };
       promises.push(postStatData(result));
     }
   }
   //this will call the data method once all postStatData is accomplished
   return $q.all(promises);
 }
```

Comment: That breaks the for loop and returns only the first item data

Comment: @AnishS. as by looking at code, it looks like working in that way.. if index match return data,, If no then how you wanted to make it working..please do add this content in question..

Comment: @AnishS. yes.. you mean to say to say you can only post one object at a time not all.. correct?

Comment: Yes only one object per call

Comment: This is the same as Brannon's above but I'm unable to get the data to my controller...comes up as undefined

Comment: @AnishS. hey i didn't copied him answer..check both time of answer..we've only 5 sec difference.. bdw above edit should work..I don;t aware of python.. otherwise I'd have help you more..

Comment: Did not insinuate in any way you copied...thank you though for the help...also is the results array intended to stay empty?

Comment: @AnishS. controller method will get data, only if you are returning data from server

Comment: I understand but I'm referring to your code..results is an array but you're pushing to 'promise'

Comment: @AnishS. no if you look at data returned to controller(inside .then function) will have `data` array, basically it contains 1st element will be first promise response, 2nd will be second promise response and so on..

Comment: running this results in "cannot read push of undefined" since promise isn't an array

Comment: @AnishS. I don't understand how does above answer helped you..as its same as that of mine...